# Split, reorder, concat inline

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, concatenate

I want to split a cell, reorder the pieces and recombine. For example:

```
| name        | reordered name |
| Page,Larry  | Larry Page     |
| Brin,Sergey | Sergey Brin    |
```

I know that `=SPLIT(A2, ",")` will split the values into the next two columns and I know that I can concatenate values with `=CONCATENATE(A2, " ", B2)`.

How do I bring these things together in a single formula?

Can I access the values from `SPLIT` and reorder them?

I know I can do `=CONCATENATE(SPLIT(A2))` (but obviously that is stupid).

In Ruby I would just do something like:

```
def reorder_name(cell)
  names = cell.split(",")
  "#{names[1]} #{names[0]}"
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the following custom function (as you're accustomed to writing in JavaScript) it is possible as well:

### Code

```
function myReverse(range) {
  var output = [];
  if(range[0].length > 1) {
    throw ("function can only handle a column range");
  } else {
    for(var i in range) {
      var name = range[i][0].split(",");
      output.push([name.reverse().join(" ")]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

### Remark

Small error handling throws a message when range contains more than 1 column.
Functions similar to `ARRAYFORMULA` to accept ranges.
Add code under Tools, Script editor. Save the script and you're ready to go !!

### Formula

The following formula will do the trick also:

```
=CONCATENATE(INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ","),1,2)," ",INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ","),1,1))
```

The `INDEX` function allows you to select particular cells, from a `CONTINUED` range. In this case you want the second split result to appear first, thus the `,1,2`, meaning first row, second column of the split result.

### Example

I've prepared an example file for you: **[split and reorder](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdGZtTDNfM05DdlBUSXhKZWJLOXBrVHc&usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 2):

Use these GSheet functions to reverse the order of the words in a string.

Write in cell A1 **`="TRICK NO THIS IS"`**

and in cell B1 **`=JOIN(" ";TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1;" "));1;FALSE)))`**

It creates `IS THIS NO TRICK` from the input in A1.

Read the formula from inside to outside:

- `SPLIT` creates and array in a row ("virtual" if the formula is used as shown) of the words in A1 separated by blanks
- `TRANSPOSE` makes a vertical array from the horizontal array
- `SORT` sorts a vertical array, 1 = single column and `FALSE` reverses the order
- `TRANSPOSE` creates again a horizontal array from the vertical reordered array
- `JOIN` concatenates the horizontal array of words into a string with blanks in betweeen in B1.

Answer (score 1):

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,999), " ",LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1))
```

Some guy on [this thread](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/345598-how-do-i-transpose-comma-separated-data-in-each-cell-and-delete-t.html) posted how to get the bits, I just wrapped them in the concat.

Note that the "+1" in the +1,999 part will be your adjustment if there are spaces or not after the comma.  Since yours does not have a space, I just dropped it back to 1 instead of 2 like in the referenced page.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to split firstname lastname into two columns, add a comma delimiter and reverse order.  Very useful for correction payroll entries.

```
            A               B            C
| firstname lastname  |  lastname  | firstname |
| JOHN BROWN          |  BROWN,    | JOHN      |
| MARTHA GREEN        |  GREEN,    | MARTHA    |
```

in column B

```
=SPLIT(TRIM(MID($A1,FIND(" ",$A1,1)+1,100)) 
&", "& TRIM(LEFT($A1,FIND(" ",$A1,1)-1))," ",FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also possible with regular expressions:

```
=regexreplace(A1,"[A-z]+,","")&" "&regexextract(A1,"\w*")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name             reordered name
Page,Larry       Larry Page 
Brin, Sergey     Sergey Brin
```

formula:

```
=index(split(A2, ","), 0, 2)&" "&index(split(A2, ","), 0, 1)
```